Modifying suggested import root in VSCode
I have a monorepo with my python code in a subfolder ./api/src. When I have a package in a Python file that I haven't yet imported, the quickfix suggests the import to the correct module, but does from api.src.package instead of just from package. I change it manually, but it'd be nice to be able to configure it import correctly.

It is not possible to configure intelliSense at this level. You can filter classes keywords from the suggestion with editor setting editor.suggest.filteredTypes. Setting up a discrete language server and do manual filtering may work but I'm afraid it is not a good idea.
